# How to enable boot manager on the slave HDD of my desktop machine?

Tags: dual-boot

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04 on the slave HDD of my desktop machine and I don't know how to enable boot manager. The system boots automatically on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You Should try running below commands:

```
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ingalex/super-boot-manager
 sudo sh -c "sed -i 's/trusty/raring/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ingalex-super-boot-manager-trusty.list"
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install super-boot-manager
 sudo apt-get install -f`
```

THen execute `super-boot-manager`

HTH!

Comment: used the block of commands succesfully i suppose but how i execute super-boot-manager? no offense i 'm in my very early 'linux' steps!

Comment: Just execute the command in terminal. Then you should be able to enable boot manager.

Comment: grub appeared before booting any OS but there is no choice for windows 7 to be booted.